# rewrite and equational reasoning in agda

Tags: agda

With rewrite I have a succinct syntax (e.g. no congruence property invoked) and I can prove :

```
-- * is associative
*-assoc : ∀ a b c → (a * b) * c ≡ a * (b * c)
*-assoc zero b c = refl
*-assoc (succ a) b c rewrite *+-dist b (a * b) c | *-assoc a b c = refl
```

however, my small brain can parse better this proof

```
--written in equational style
*-assoc' : ∀ a b c → (a * b) * c ≡ a * (b * c)
*-assoc' zero b c = refl
*-assoc' (succ a) b c = (succ a * b) * c  ≡⟨ refl ⟩
                        (b + a * b) * c ≡⟨ *+-dist b (a * b) c ⟩
                        b * c + (a * b) * c ≡⟨ cong (λ x -> b * c + x) (*-assoc a b c)  ⟩
                        b * c + a * (b * c)  ≡⟨ refl ⟩
                        (succ a) * (b * c) ∎
```

but I have to specify which subterm to 'transform' by invoking congruence.

Is there a way to combine rewrite and equational writing to get rid of the congruence mention ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there might be tactics in agda for this here : http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.agda/6867. the bin file is actually straight agda.

Comment: I've often found the same problem. I'd consider adding a lemma proving that `b * c + (a * b) * c ≡ b * c + a * (b * c)`, mutually recursive with `*-assoc`, and proving *that* one with `rewrite`. However, sometimes adding such lemmas makes termination checking fail, because it's harder to see that the recursive calls are on smaller terms; that should not be the case here, but I haven't tried.
(Tactics are a better solution, but I'm not sure there are fully usable solutions available).